# Unable to run module in python with Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost

Written a c++ program and trying to make it compatible with python using **Boost.Python**. Running the c++ program in Eclipse works fine. However when I create a shared library (vectorEg.so) out of that c++ program and trying to import it in python it shows an error.

```
In [1]: import vectorEg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fd697b4a9962> in <module>()
----> 1 import vectorEg

ImportError: ./vectorEg.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4itppplIdEENS_3VecIT_EERKS3_S5_
```

C++ Code :

```
#include <itpp/itbase.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace itpp;

vec testFunc()
{
  //Declare vectors and matricies:
  vec a, b, c;
  a = linspace(1.0, 2.0, 10);
  //Use a string of values to define a vector:
  b = "0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0";
  //Add two vectors:
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(vectorEg)
{
        using namespace boost::python;
        using namespace itpp;
        def("testFunc", testFunc);
}
```

Also Tried using itpp::Vec as vector declaration.

```
#include <itpp/itbase.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace itpp;

itpp::Vec<double> testFunc()
{
  //Declare vectors and matricies:
  itpp::Vec<double> a, b, c;
  a = linspace(1.0, 2.0, 10);
  //Use a string of values to define a vector:
  b = "0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0";
  //Add two vectors:
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(vectorEg)
{
        using namespace boost::python;
        using namespace itpp;
        def("testFunc", testFunc);
}
```

For compilation and creation of shared library i am using this piece of code

```
g++ -c vectorEg.cpp -litpp -o vectorEg.o -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7/
g++ -shared vectorEg.o -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -o vectorEg.so
sudo cp vectorEg.so /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages # adding file to python path.
```

Also for i have installed IT++

```
sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev # for ubuntu 16.0.4
```

Comment: `-litpp` belongs in the link line (where you build the library) not the compile one. (Don't know if that is the issue though; it's looking for this: `itpp::Vec<double> itpp::operator+<double>(itpp::Vec<double> const&, itpp::Vec<double> const&)`)

Comment: Tried with that one as well

Comment: @Mat added updated code